# How many digit number I have to write if I write $2^n$ exponential sequence from 1 to $2^{1000}$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

If I write sequence $2^n$ exponential sequence, "1,2,4,8,16,..." until I reach $2^{1000}$, how many digit number I have to write ?

I try using the method that work for linear sequence by writing some first sequence and find the pattern.

1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,65536,131072,262144,524288,1048576,2097152,4194304,8388608,16777216,33554432,67108864,134217728,268435456,536870912,1073741824,...

The total digit number seem to be repeat (1+1+1+1)+(2+2+2)+(3+3+3)+(4+4+4+4)+(5+5+5)+(6+6+6)+(7+7+7+7)+(8+8+8)+(9+9+9)+...

The total digit number from I have to write from 1 to 536870912 or $2^{29}$ is 4(1)+3(2)+3(3)+4(4)+3(5)+3(6)+4(7)+3(8)+3(9) = 147.

From this, I get

- Total digit number from I have to write for number $2^{(10n-10)}$,$2^{(10n-9)}$,$2^{(10n-8)}$,$2^{(10n-7)}$ is $3n-2$ if n>0
- Total digit number from I have to write for number $2^{(10n-6)}$,$2^{(10n-5)}$,$2^{(10n-4)}$ is $3n-1$ if n>0
- Total digit number from I have to write for number $2^{(10n-3)}$,$2^{(10n-2)}$,$2^{(10n-1)}$ is $3n$ if n>0
- Total digit number from I have to write from 1 to $2^{(10n-1)}$ is $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \biggl(4(3k-2)+3(3k-1)+3(3k)\biggl)$ if n>0

So, the total digit number from I have to write from 1 to $2^{1000}$ is $(3(101)-2)+\sum_{k=0}^{100} \biggl(4(3k-2)+3(3k-1)+3(3k)\biggl) = 301+150400 = 150701$.

Am I get the correct answer ? I am not sure since it is a method for linear sequence not exponential sequence.

If my answer isn't correct answer, what is the correct answer ?

Comment: I think that logarithms will help you.  E.g. $log_{10} (2^{1000}) = 301.03$ so it has $302$ digits.  $log_{10} (2)$ is irrational so the pattern won't be simple.

Comment: @badjohn Oh, the method for linear sequence doesn't work for exponential sequence as  I suspect. So, how can I calculate it ?

Comment: "The total digit number seem to be repeat" This is false. If that were the case would imply that $\log_{10} 2$ is rational, and that's not the case.

Comment: It breaks for example at $\cdots + (28 + 28 + 28 + 28) + (29 + 29+ 29) + (30 + 30 + 30) + (31 + 31+ 31) + \cdots$

Comment: @jjagmath Thank you. I know my answer is wrong and the method doesn't work. So, how can I calculate it ?

Comment: Just calculate the sum with a calculator. I see no other way.

Comment: I believe that it necessarily involves many calculations, I doubt this can be done without the help of a computer/calculator.

Comment: Your apparent pattern is because $log_{10} 2$ is approximately $0.3$ but if you go far enough then pattern will break because it is not exactly $0.3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addendum added to give an exact answer.

---

Let $\displaystyle M = \log_{10} (2) \approx 0.301029995.$ 
This implies that for any non-negative integer $k$, 
$\displaystyle \log_{10}\left(2^k\right) = kM.$

For any Real number $(r)$, let $~\lfloor r\rfloor~$ (i.e. the *floor* function) 
denote the largest integer $~\leq r.$

Any positive integer $(n)$ that does not have form $~\displaystyle (10)^k ~: ~k \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~$ will require 
$\displaystyle \lfloor 1 + \log_{10}(n)\rfloor = 1 + \lfloor \log_{10}(n)\rfloor~$ digits to write.

Therefore, for any non-negative integer $(k)$, the number $~\displaystyle \left(2^k\right)~$ will require 
$\displaystyle 1 + \lfloor kM\rfloor~$ digits to write.

Therefore, the exact value is

$$1001 + \sum_{k=0}^{1000} \left\lfloor kM\right\rfloor. \tag1 $$

The challenge is to turn the expression in (1) above into an exact value.  The OP's (i.e. original poster's) approach was (in effect) to assume that :

- $\displaystyle 0 \leq k \leq 3 \implies \left\lfloor kM\right\rfloor = 0.$
- $\displaystyle 4 \leq k \leq 6 \implies \left\lfloor kM\right\rfloor = 1.$
- $\displaystyle 7 \leq k \leq 9 \implies \left\lfloor kM\right\rfloor = 2.$
- $\displaystyle 10 \leq k \leq 13 \implies \left\lfloor kM\right\rfloor = 3.$
- $\displaystyle 14 \leq k \leq 16 \implies \left\lfloor kM\right\rfloor = 4.$
- $\displaystyle 17 \leq k \leq 19 \implies \left\lfloor kM\right\rfloor = 5.$
- $\cdots $
- $\displaystyle 990 \leq k \leq 993 \implies \left\lfloor kM\right\rfloor = 297.$
- $\displaystyle 994 \leq k \leq 996 \implies \left\lfloor kM\right\rfloor = 298.$
- $\displaystyle 997 \leq k \leq 999 \implies \left\lfloor kM\right\rfloor = 299.$
- $\displaystyle k = 1000 \implies \left\lfloor kM\right\rfloor = 300.$

This is close but immediately seen to be wrong, given the approximation for $M$.

For example:

- $\displaystyle \left\lfloor 990 \times M\right\rfloor = 298.$
- $\displaystyle \left\lfloor 1000 \times M\right\rfloor= 301.$

Personally, I know of know way to get an exact value except to have a computer program evaluate the expression in (1) above.  Certainly, the approximation for $~\log_{10}(2)~$ given at the start of this answer should result in an exact answer, since the summation is only going up to $(k = 1000).$

---

**Addendum**
A computer program evaluated the expression in (1) above to $151167.$

Also, the computer program gives the approximation for $~\log_{10}(2)~$ as $0.3010299956639812$.

The approximation for $\log_{10}(2)$ that I gave at the start of my answer was from my handheld calculator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you calculate the exact value with the computer program ? So, I will accept your post as the answer for this question.

Comment: The number burned into my brain from log tables many years ago in school is $0.30103$ and my calculator says $0.30102999566$.

Comment: @wnattosignin See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.

Comment: @badjohn See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.

Comment: A quite poor value even for a handheld calculator.  Shows 9 decimals but the 4th is wrong.

Comment: @user2661923 I think badjohn wants to point out the typo in the value of $M$ at the beginning of your answer.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks for the assist.  I transposed two of the decimal digits.  Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in Mathematica in the most direct way possible gives $151167$ as the output of

```
StringLength["" <> ToString /@ (2^Range[0, 1000])]
```

If we remove the `StringLength` on the outside, then `"" <> ToString /@ (2^Range[0, 1000])` will print out all $151167$ digits: an output that looks like

```
"12481632641282565121...24386837205668069376"
```